# Multiple DbContext. "A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed."

Tags: dbcontext, asp.net-core-webapi, ef-core-2.0

I've been working on ASP.NET Core Web API. I've receive "A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe." when I try to add new object to my database.

Let's show the code:
Firstly, please look at my controller. This controller is using 3 repositories and each repository is using dataContext. DataContext for each repository is the same.

```
public partial class TestDeviceController : BaseController
{
    private readonly ITestDeviceRepository _testDeviceRepository;
    private readonly IBridgeRepository _bridgeRepository;
    private readonly IDeviceRepository _deviceRepository;

    public TestDeviceController(ITestDeviceRepository testDeviceRepository, IBridgeRepository bridgeRepository, IDeviceRepository deviceRepository)
    {
        _testDeviceRepository = testDeviceRepository;
        _bridgeRepository = bridgeRepository;
        _deviceRepository = deviceRepository;
    }

}
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]TestDevicePostDTO testDevicePost)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return BadRequest(ModelState);

        var testDevice = new TestDeviceDTO();
        Mapper.Map(testDevicePost, testDevice);

        await _testDeviceRepository.Add(testDevice);
        return Ok();
    }
```

As you see the Add action is beeing called from testDeviceRepository so, please find my TestDeviceRepository. Now required is also one word about DeviceSpecificRepository. It is an abstraction created for testDevice and bridge devices which have the same actions.

```
    public class TestDeviceRepository : DeviceSpecificRepository<TestDeviceDTO, TestDevice>, ITestDeviceRepository
{
    public TestDeviceRepository(DataContext dataContext, IDeviceRepository deviceRepository) : base(dataContext, deviceRepository)
    {
    }

    public async Task Add(TestDeviceDTO testDeviceDto)
    {
        var device = _deviceRepository.CreateDevice(testDeviceDto).Result;
        device.Type = DeviceType.TestDevice;

        await CreateDeviceSpecific(testDeviceDto, device);

        await _dataContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }}
```

In action Add, there are called _deviceRepository and DeviceSpecificRepository, and I think something here is the issue. Device repository created one context and testDeviceRepository created another one.

But I've added in Startup.cs:

```
            services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings:default").Value));

            services.AddScoped<IDeviceRepository, DeviceRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<ITestDeviceRepository, TestDeviceRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IBridgeRepository, BridgeReporsitory>();
```

As I understand default dbContext lifetime is scoped, so there should be with dbContext, because there is one context per request. The solution work with lifetime singleton, but I would like to avoid keep all time context open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are mixing blocking calls like `.Result` in an async await method.

```
var device = _deviceRepository.CreateDevice(testDeviceDto).Result;
```

should be awaited.

```
public async Task Add(TestDeviceDTO testDeviceDto) {
    var device = await _deviceRepository.CreateDevice(testDeviceDto);
    device.Type = DeviceType.TestDevice;

    await CreateDeviceSpecific(testDeviceDto, device);

    await _dataContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Comment: Agree, it was my test, to check if the solution will work properly with synchronous function calling. But it doesn't help. In my code I'm using the code as in your comment .